# Symfony2 error while display entity related ManyToOne

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine, relation, many-to-one

I am trying to display a "CategorieActivite" in an activite.html twig page.

I have 2 entities. The first one is Activite. The second one is CategorieActivite.

I have put annotations in the Activite. 
I have prepared my query with join in ActiviteRepository.
It's ok in my database (foreign key).

BUT i get this error :
Method "CategorieActivite" for object "AssoFranceRussie\MainBundle\Entity\Activite" does not exist in (in my twig page)

Do I have to do something else to get some entity data from another entity?
Thanks
EB

The code :

```
class Activite
{

    // $categorieActiviteId lié à l'entité CategorieActivite
    // ManyToOne
    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="AssoFranceRussie\MainBundle\Entity\CategorieActivite")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="categorie_activite_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    private $categorieActiviteId;   

...
}
```

ActiviteRepository :

```
public function getAllActivites()
    {
    $query = $this->getEntityManager()->createQuery(
      'SELECT a,c,n 
        FROM AssoFranceRussieMainBundle:Activite a 
        JOIN a.categorieActiviteId c 
        JOIN a.niveauActiviteId n 
        ORDER BY a.nom ASC '
        );   


    return $query->getResult();

    }
```

And in the twig html:

```
<p><strong>{{activite.CategorieActivite.libelle}}</strong></p>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should create getter for $categorieActiviteId property. 
So in Activite class you should have

```
public function getCategorieActivite() {
    return $this->categorieActiviteId;
}
```

and in twig you should have:

```
<p><strong>{{activite.getCategorieActivite.libelle}}</strong></p>
```

Dont forget libelle have to be public method or property

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your help. It works now. 
Actually i had already the getter with annotation in the class Activite. So, I should have write in twig {{activite.categorieActiviteId.libelle}} instead of {{activite.categorieActivite.libelle}}. The 2 ways to access the data work.

the getter in Activite class:

```
/**
 * Get categorieActiviteId
 *
 * @return \AssoFranceRussie\MainBundle\Entity\CategorieActivite 
 */
public function getCategorieActiviteId()
{
    return $this->categorieActiviteId;
}
```